# Eddy current damping compensation

Tags: electromagnetism, control-system

I have a magnetically permeable element (98% pure iron) vibrating at 3-5Hz between two electromagnets (with iron cores) which is experiencing too much damping, presumably due to eddy current losses.

I know I can reduce this damping by constructing my vibrating element from thin laminated layers, or by using an electrically non-conductive material (ferrite?).

Is it possible to produce a damping reduction via control system? I'm imagining sensing the displacement/velocity of the core versus time and using this to somehow vary the power output to the solenoid coils.

If it's possible, I'd be grateful for details on how it would work.

The vibrating element is cylindrical with approx 35mm diameter. My end goal is to electromagnetically control the (negative) stiffness of a system without adding much damping.

Comment: do your electromagnets have magnetic cores?

Comment: Do you want to oscillate the core position for a longer time? What is your system? Some lab shaker? Or more like a levitating magnet?

Comment: Eddy current compensation will just boost high frequency gain.  Damping is an impedance ratio of real/reactive power is best improved by reducing the real eddy current loss if that is the cause. What freq? Core thickness? Matl?

Comment: @Jasen see edits

Comment: @jDAQ see edits

Comment: So you want it to keep oscillating but the oscillations are decaying (at all or too fast)? What is starting the oscillations? What type of sensors could you use to measure "displacement/velocity"?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Is it possible to produce a damping reduction via control system", but you could definitely implement a controller that tracks a sine or other periodic signal, that way your oscillation would last longer/forever. Since the magnets seem to already for the job (your actuators are good), now you have to figure what type of sensors you could use and what would be the best for this case.

Comment: @jDAQ correct, oscillations are decaying much too quickly. The oscillations are due to forces that are external to my system. I believe a high accuracy laser displacement sensor could work and could be differentiated to get velocity.

Comment: @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75 see edits

Comment: How do you measure damping? A current controlled acceleration will have a linear response with losses for coupling and limits for current and a frequency response limited by mass and current with a 2nd order position response.  So how much is the damping and how us it measured?

Comment: @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75 my assessment that the damping is 'too much' is so far limited to just visual observation of the decay rate of the oscillations resulting from an impulse. With coils powered I'd estimate the damping ratio to be 10-20%. Unpowered it's just the damping of supporting coil springs, so 1% or less. I plan to actually measure decay rates with an accelerometer. My ultimate target is 2-3 percent damping ratio under power.

Comment: so do you want to lower impedance of Z=Sqrt(L/C) while reducing fo Res. frequency to raise Q?  If R is fixed and known, that is what needs to be done.

Comment: To increase mutual coupling or Inductance, reduce the air gap like a speaker except you have fixed coil and moving iron, which could be a rare earth magnet.

Answer (score 0):

If you can characterize  (i.e. predict) the damping then that can be fed into the control system inverted to reduce the damping effect.

Answer (score 0):

You want a control system for damping. What you would need is a coil in the field of the vibrating magnet, connected to a resistor. When vibrating, current will be induced in the coil. The resistor will dissipate some energy, which will be extracted from the magnet, so it will be "damped". With some electronics, you could regulate how much energy will be dissipated in the resistor. You also need a sensor that measures the amount of vibration, and a feedback loop to complete the control system.

You could, of course, combine this coil with one of the electromagnets, which are also coils, if you figure out how to separate the voltages for powering the electromagnet and those from the induction by the vibrating magnet.

The same coil can also be used as a sensor.

Good Luck!

Comment: His problem is that he "... is experiencing too much damping", the resistor part will not help. If only the OP could better describe the system/requirements or post some _good_ pictures of the system the answers could actually be on point.

Comment: @jDAQ Sure, OP could reduce the eddy current losses from the massive core by going to a laminated core, and introduce controllable losses to a resistor as I described.